# Id and class selectors for buttons - previously working

Tags: html, css

Good Afternoon to whom ever is listening! Any help or even an insult would be useful. I am having trouble putting together a small profile switch/tab display - however, the switch buttons work correctly when the ids are the same; but i'd like to use the same html but with a different css so they dont clash on the same page.

https://jsfiddle.net/limtu/h8t6cc78/

```
        <div id="profile2">
    <img height="180px" width="180px" src="http://#/files/theme/nat2.jpg">
    <a href="http://www.fightingfitlondon.co.uk/nat-roberson.html">Nat Roberson</a>
    <input id="main2" type="radio" name="menu" checked>
    <label for="main"></label>
    <input id="mail2" type="radio" name="menu">
    <label for="mail"></label>
    <input id="menu2" type="radio" name="menu">
    <label for="menu"></label>
    <div id="menu-content2">
        <span id="info2">About:<br/><br/>Nat joined All Stars Boxing Gym in London when he was 9 years old. He had his first bout at 11 and boxed competitively for 8 years until he was 19.</span>
        <span id="contacts2">
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
        </span>
        <span id="more2">
            <a href="#/nat-roberson.html">Profile</a>
            <a href="">Timetables</a>
            <a href="">Activities</a>
            <a href="">Speciality</a>
        </span>
    </div>
```

i.e just adding #profile2 { etc, but it disables the button switches. any help would greatly appreciated! Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/limtu/h8t6cc78/embedded/result/

Comment: What is the expected behavior? For the tab to change color when you click it? Not sure what you're asking for help with...

Comment: To target multiple elements, use a `class`. Never use same `id` for multiple elements.

Comment: I just want to create a seperate css for the same html, so that more than one of these profiles boxes can be on the same page and not clash. when more than one is placed, the tab selector stops working. This is what it originally looks like : https://jsfiddle.net/limtu/h8t6cc78/1/    - Im trying to create a second css for a the same html but using different class name, so instead of #profile, id like #profile2 but also in the css so they dont clash.

Comment: Yeah.. You've gotten ID happy where you should be using classes.

Comment: am i going to have to write the css again, or do you think their is away i can just rename the id -

Comment: @Limtu I'd suggest re-writing it with classes where necessary.It shouldn't take long as you have all the properties defined already. Will just need to rename all the selectors to the appropriate classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem you have is that you use `id`'s everywhere. Instead, you should use *only* `classes` if there are going to be more than one profile. This is because you should never have two elements with the same `id` - that's what `classes` are for.

However, the problem with using classes is that you can't associate a `label` with an `input field` that has no `id`. So, instead of using `labels`, you should use `::after` pseudo elements. Clicking on pseudo elements will also trigger the parent. By applying a solid `background` to these pseudo elements and using `position:absolute; top:0; left:0;`, you can cover/hide the radio button but still activate it without it having an `id`.

To only allow one `input[type=radio]` within one profile to be selected at once, you should give them all the same `name`, but different `value`. You can also now target these individually by their `value` using `input[value=your-value]`.

However, if you leave it at that, you will only be able to have one tab selected across all of your profiles. So what you need to do is wrap everything in a `form` element. This way despite the radio buttons having the same `name`s and `value`s in every profile, they won't affect other profiles on the same page because they are associated with different `forms`.

Frankly, it took a lot of time and work, but here's your fixed profile page: https://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/h8t6cc78/5/ I put in three profiles to demonstrate that it works with multiple profiles. The `id`'s that each of the forms have are not necessary for this to work. They're just there to demonstrate what `id`'s could/should be used for. An `id` is used to **id**entify a *unique* element, to distinguish it from other elements.

Comment: Dear Ilpo, Thank you so much for spending your time to write that incredibly useful information. I have been struggling with the class, id and selector for a while now. ive just spent the last 3 hours trying to figure it out! Thank you Ilpo, thats really really kind of you. Im just taking a look now and learning from your lesson.

Comment: just looking now, so for every new profile, i have to create it using the <form id>? i.e. <form id="someone-else" class="profile"> then followed by the rest? Thanks again

Comment: `id` isn't necessary. It's just there in case you want to distinguish them from one-other somehow. You can leave it out if you want to. The `form` is the container and I explained why I used a `form` instead of a `div`.

Comment: I improved my answer a bit, hope that clarifies it for you.

Comment: Thankyou very much for taking the time to explain it to me. Im trying to get to grips with your example and learn from there, but its much clearer to me  now. Thanks again